# How to make "echo"ed line editable in an interactive shell script?

Tags: bash, shell

I have the following problem: in an interactive script, when asking for input, I want to display a suggestion and make it editable. It is a similar functionality to "arrow up and edit the last command" in a command prompt, except without the "arrow up". I tried several different things but no success so far.

These are the things I tried:

1) Get input from editor, like so:

```
echo "$SUGGESTION\c"
INPUT=`ed -` # problem with this approach is that 'ed' starts in command mode 
             # by default, and I would need input mode
```

2) Use read -e

```
echo "$SUGGESTION\c"
read -e INPUT # doesn't work as advertised
```

After extensive Googling I am convinced that the 2) should work, but it doesn't. First of all, I cannot delete the $SUGGESTION without typing some input first; after some characters are typed, backspace deletes the whole line, not just one character.

So my question is: how to make "read -e" work or is there another approach to solve this? Your help is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

It does work as advertised, but you need an extra parameter to do what you want:

```
read -e -i "$SUGGESTION" INPUT
```

Unfortunately, that's only available in Bash 4.

If you have a C compiler and `readline` available, here's a quick hack that you could use. Save the following to `myread.c` (or whatever) and compile it (you'll need to link with `readline`). For GCC, that would be: `gcc -o myread myread.c -lreadline`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <readline/readline.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    if (argc != 2)
        return 1;

    // stuff the input buffer with the default value
    char *def = argv[1];
    while (*def) {
        rl_stuff_char(*def);
        def++;
    }

    // let the user edit
    char *input = readline(0);
    if (!input)
        return 1;
    // write out the result to standard error
    fprintf(stderr, "%s", input);
    return 0;
}
```

You can use it like this:

```
myread "$SUGGESTION" 2> some_temp_file
if [ $? -eq 0 ] ; then 
  # some_temp_file contains the edited value
fi
```

Lots of room for improvement, but I guess it's a start.

Comment: Mat, read doesn't accept the "-i" option ( I am on Mac if it makes a difference ) read: -i: invalid option
read: usage: read [-ers] [-u fd] [-t timeout] [-p prompt] [-a array] [-n nchars] [-d delim] [name ...]. The following format "read -e "$SUGGESTION" INPUT" doesn't work either, but I suppose that all hangs on the "-i" option?

Comment: GNU bash, version 3.2.48(1)-release-(x86_64-apple-darwin11)

Comment: Sorry, don't know how to do what you want with that. The `-i` parameter appeared in bash 4. I don't see how you could do what you want without that switch (which is probably why it was added...).

Comment: I could imagine reading input one char at a time, but this is one painful thought.. thanks anyway!

Comment: @Vadim: you can compile Bash 4.x on MacOS X easily enough; I've done it.  I have not installed it; I would only do so using a name such as bash4, carefully not overwriting or modifying the system-provided bash 3.x.

Comment: @Jonathan: I am trying to do just that (just installed MacPorts and Pallet). However I'd like to believe there is a way in earlier bash versions (for reasons of compatibility)... the hope lives!

Comment: @Vadim: I don't wish to dampen your hopes, but I don't recommending holding your breath while waiting for a Bash 3.x answer that works.

Comment: @Jonathan While I realise that, I am looking for a portable solution (Mac, Cygwin, RedHat).. perhaps I should change the implementation language while my little project is in its early stage. If only I knew which...

Comment: @Vadim: added a tiny bit of C (that is as portable as the readline library - so quite a lot) that could help you out or get you started on something more robust.

Comment: @Mat amazing!! thank you very much! Actually I just compiled and installed bash 4.0 — still the same error (will try again tomorrow). if all else fails then C is the way

Comment: @Mat Yep, the problem was the #! line, it was /bin/sh intead of /bin/bash. Now this works beautifully — thank you so much!!